# Highcharts polar steps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a Highcharts polar chart, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgwf23me/

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 11,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  }
},
```

The problem is that the yAxis max seems to go by steps of 5. With max on 11, the rendered max step is 15.

How do I change this behaviour to be steps of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `endOnTick` being `true`. From the [`max` API description](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max):

> If the `endOnTick` option is true, the `max` value might be rounded up.

Set this to `false`, and the axis should have the correct height.

You may also want to adjust the ticks to make the lines show up appropriately. This can be done in a number of ways, using `tickPositions`, `tickPositioner`, `tickInterval`...

My simple suggestion is to do it like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgwf23me/1/)):

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 11,
    endOnTick: false, // For axis height
    tickPositions: [0,11], // For grid lines
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted :)